# Change 3rd party iframe url to forward not popup (_blank)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup, click

I am constructed the below script but am now struggling as I notice the url I intend to use opens a new tab and I want it to just forward:

```
<script>
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
var cookie = readCookie("do_redirect");
console.log(cookie);
if(cookie == 1){
console.log('inside if');
setTimeout(function(){
 var links = $('#main2568_0').contents()[0].links;
  console.log(links);
  links[Math.floor((Math.random() * links.length-1) + 1)].click();
}, 1000);
}
console.log($("body").find("#inst23"));
</script>
```

So you see when the cookie is successful than the code grabs the url from the 3rd party iframe and clicks on it and this opens a new tab. How can I grab the url and ensure it is opened in same window. I have no control over the 3rd party site. I notice the target is _blank so any chance overwriting? Or if click() doesn't work would popstate or something similar work?

Comment: It shouldn't be even possible to grab a link from a 3rd party page ... I doubt the code would work as you've described ..?

Comment: it works. Why write on a post if you don't even know much? It's a third party iframe. The link can be grabbed it creating an _blank issue

Comment: I know enough to say that it shouldn't be possible. I also know, that if you've a link, then you can access its `href` and replace the value of `src` of the iframe with that `href`, _blank problem tackled ...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I don't understand what you mean. The code above works also I have seen it on my site working. My only issue is the link extracted by the code above gets target _blank. Was hoping can over-ride it with _self or something. Or even manipulate the above but don't understand to extract link and then not open in new tab upon click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works now with below change:

```
window.location.replace(links[Math.floor((Math.random() * links.length-1) + 1)]);
```